# Ubuntu 12.04 fails to load gnome/unity (?) after login

Tags: 12.04, login, macbook

When I try to log in to my account, I am stuck looking at the desktop background, with none of the unity UI (menu bar, launch bar on the left etc) loaded.

The desktop operates fine - I can right click, select change desktop background, and get into a functional system preferences menu in that manner.  That doesn't exactly help, though :P

I'm running as a dual boot on a macbook pro (5,1 from memory).

Booting in recovery mode and then resuming will get me to a functioning desktop (apparently without video drivers loaded), but it's ridiculously unresponsive (the whole boot process in both modes is incredibly slow, actually - it takes minutes on a ssd).

Any idea what's going wrong?  I assume some component is failing to load and is therefore nuking the boot process.